# Best practice to use when building an api and shipping compiled files to client

Tags: node.js, api, software-design, rest

I am currently building an api that i will ship to my client, I started building using node js and was going to use one of its compilation tools to ship an executable or a binary file for the user to run on their server on premises , is this the best technical way?

Comment: I would also use swagger

Comment: yes me and my team are using swagger as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using: 
1) Node js 
2) [Nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe) for compilation 
3) [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) for documentation 
4) [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [Chai](https://www.chaijs.com/) for testing